# 3 Questions about having to do a hard shutdown and reboot

Tags: shutdown, reboot, nixos, plasma5

When I attempt to do a soft reboot or shutdown, the display hangs and the system is unresponsive for an inordinate amount of time. I therefore have to shutdown or reboot my setup by holding the power button.

3 questions:

1. I assume this indicates there are some problems. How severe?
2. How detrimental to the system is it to always have to do a hard reboot or reset?
3. How do I identify the culprit for my shutdown problems?

System info (what I think is most relevant):

- NixOS 18.03
- KDE Plasma 5 Desktop

I added a video that demonstrates the problem as well:
https://youtu.be/e9cqTzmgSws

--

Here's a pastebin of the logs during shutdown
http://nixpaste.lbr.uno/oIus0Aqk?nix

--

For anybody who runs into this problem in the future, I did find that if I Suspend my computer once after booting everything shuts down just fine. Why? I don't know. That is my current workaround.

Comment: Define 'cannot'.  What happens when you try?

Comment: Are you talking about shutting down/rebooting from the GUI? Does `shutdown -r now` not work from a terminal? Log files usually give you clues on where your issues are...

Comment: @DopeGhoti, question modified per your request. The system is unresponsive for any software initiated shutdown or reboot.

Comment: @saleetzo, I have tried `shutdown -r now`. It makes the system hang.

Comment: What do you mean "display hangs" - your gui?  Black screen with blinking cursor?  Are there any indications that the system halt is running/has run?  It could simply be an ACPI power off thing... and the system is actually shut down, just the hardware isn't obeying the poweroff signal

Comment: @DavidWest we could definitely use some more detail when it it comes to your symptoms. When it hangs... are you able to hit your num lock or caps lock keys and see them turn on/off? If, ofc, you have lights on your keyboard. What about looking at your log files to see if it shutdown properly?

Comment: @saleetzo I checked the num lock and caps lock lights and they do not toggle. I also added a pastebin to the logs from the failed shutdown.

Comment: @ivanian I made a video of exactly how it behaves during shutdown and copied a link to the YouTube upload. It hangs on the KDE Plasma workspace as soon as I start to shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a more precise definition of "cannot", it's difficult to answer your first question.

For your second, doing a "hard" shutdown or reboot can lead to several problems:

- "Temporary" files which an application would ordinarily clean up not being removed, leading to wasted disk space
- Incomplete filesystem I/O transactions leading to lost or corrupted data on your filesystem, possibly including important data or application binaries

Your third question is tied to your first, and in turn to your premise:  When you say you "cannot" shut down without any further information, it's nearly impossible to determine precisely what you mean; much less the cause for what you are seeing.

Comment: I defined "cannot" more precisely.